# Python regex is not extracting a substring from my log file

Tags: python, regex, parsing, log-analysis

I'm using

```
date = re.findall(r"^(?:\w{3} ){2}\d{2} (?:[\d]{2}:){2}\d{2} \d{4}$", message)
```

in Python 2.7 to extract the substrings:

```
Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015
Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015
```

from a log file like this:

```
1424,Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51
1424,Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29
```

It is not working, and I'm required to use regex for this task, otherwise I would have split() it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your sub-strings doesn't began from the first part of your string you dont need to assert position at start and end of the string so you can remove `^` and `$`
:

```
>>> s ="""
1424,Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51
1424,Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29"""
>>> date = re.findall(r"(?:\w{3} ){2}\d{2} (?:[\d]{2}:){2}\d{2} \d{4}", s)
>>> date
['Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015', 'Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015']
```

Also as an alternative proposition you can just use a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  :

```
>>> date = re.findall(r"(?<=\d{4},).*", s)
>>> date
['Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51', 'Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29']
```

or without using regex you can use `str.split()` and `str.partition()` for such tasks :

```
>>> s ="""
1424,Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51
1424,Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29"""

>>> [i.partition(',')[-1] for i in s.split('\n')]
['Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51', 'Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29']
```

Comment: Thanks Kasra AD.  I was thinking that ```^``` and ```$``` meant ignore anything before and after, but your explanation clears things up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a simple way to do this is just match by the commas

```
message = '1424,Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51 1424,Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015,29'
date = re.findall(r",(.*?),", message)
print date

>>> ['Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015', 'Thu Feb 05 13:45:08 2015']
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.regex101.com/r/wC9xS4/1)

Comment: as you can see in my example, I'm working with multiple lines, and the task requires regex. thx tho.

Comment: @mdandr and I'm using regex? is this not working? if so can you provide a sample file and I'll test it on my end?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks I didn't see that.  However I needed a more explicit regular expression, and my problem was that I was starting my regex with a ```^``` and ending it with a ```$```.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `regex`, use `split`.

```
line = "1424,Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015,51"
date = line.split(",")[1]
print date
>>>Wed Feb 04 13:29:49 2015
```

Comment: I was doing that, but I found that the task at hand requires regular expressions.

Comment: No, it doesn't, as demonstrated above.

Comment: As I state in my question, "the task requires regex" so that means I'm looking for solution involving regular expressions.